# Проблема отправки формы

Tags: php, форма

Почему письма по исполнению такого кода не приходят на почту:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
if(isset($_POST["sendemail"]) && $_POST["sendemail"] == "") {

$refferer = getenv('HTTP_REFERER');
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]); 
$subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST["subject"]); 
$tema = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode("Письмо с сайта")."?=";

$name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) : '';  
$name_laser = isset($_POST["name_laser"]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["name_laser"]) : ''; 
$cost = isset($_POST["cost"]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["cost"]) : ''; 
$ask_text = isset($_POST["ask_text"]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["ask_text"]) : ''; 


$message_to_myemail = "<b>Здравствуйте, Вам заявка с сайта!</b> <br>
    Заявка из: \"$subject\" <br><br>
    <table style='width: 100%;'>";

if (!empty($name)) {
        $message_to_myemail .= "
    <tr style='background-color: #f8f8f8;'>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>Имя Клиента:</b></td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$name</td>
    </tr>";
}

if (!empty($name_laser)) {
        $message_to_myemail .= "
        <tr style='background-color: #f8f8f8;'>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>Название устройства:</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$name_laser</td>
        </tr>";
}

if (!empty($cost)) {
        $message_to_myemail .= "
        <tr style='background-color: #f8f8f8;'>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>Цена покупки по договору:</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$cost</td>
        </tr>";
}

if (!empty($ask_text)) {
        $message_to_myemail .= "
        <tr style='background-color: #f8f8f8;'>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>Вопрос:</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$ask_text</td>
        </tr>";
}

$message_to_myemail .= "
    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>
            <b>Телефон клиента:</b>
        </td>
        <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$phone</td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>
    ";


$message_to_myemail .= "Источник (ссылка): $refferer";

$myemail = "sales@profbeauty.ru"; // e-mail администратора

// Отправка письма администратору сайта
mail($myemail, $tema, $message_to_myemail, "From: Sitename <admin@profbeauty.ru> \r\n Reply-To: Sitename \r\n"."MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"."Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" );

}
```

Comment: уже был такой вопрос

Comment: Как у вас настроена почта на сервере? Если никак, то о чём речь?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать SMTP, попробуйте через PHPMailer

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]